# which of the two is more efficient to add new columns in a data.table? And why?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the two methods below to add columns to an existing data.table. One is the chaining of data.table calls using `[]` and the other is the classic single variables addition each time by `:=`

Both methods utlize the same memory (1.66GB) at the end but one of the two looks around `15 ~ 20%` faster.
My question is:
is this speed increase a fluke or a real one?
And if real, why is it so?

```r
library(pacman)
p_load(reprex, data.table,magrittr,pryr)
mem_used()
#> 53.7 MB
# initialise a large data.table 
dt1 <- data.table(x= 1:5e7, y = 5e7:1)
mem_used()
#> 454 MB
```

### Method 1

```r
system.time(dt2 <- dt1[,a:=log(x)][,b:=log(y)][,c := a + b])
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   1.379   0.589   1.968
mem_used()
#> 1.66 GB
```

#### release the memory to start again

```r
rm(dt1,dt2)
gc()
#>           used (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used (Mb)
#> Ncells  795598 42.5    1291680   69.0   1291680   69
#> Vcells 1424205 10.9  234120480 1786.2 201449048 1537
mem_used()
#> 55.9 MB
dt1 <- data.table(x= 1:5e7, y = 5e7:1)
mem_used()
#> 456 MB
```

### Method 2

```r
system.time({
dt1[,a:=log(x)]
dt1[,b:=log(y)]
dt1[,c := a + b]
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   1.207   0.472   1.679
mem_used()
#> 1.66 GB
```

As you see Method 2 is 15 ~ 17% faster. Why?

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference isn't significant : repeating calculation many times (default = 100) with `microbenchmark` shows there's no difference

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(chain={dt2 <- dt1[,a:=log(x)][,b:=log(y)][,c := a + b]},
                               seq = {dt1[,a:=log(x)]
                                 dt1[,b:=log(y)]
                                 dt1[,c := a + b]})

Unit: seconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 chain 3.056398 3.123273 3.207696 3.204743 3.270068 3.500883   100
   seq 3.060816 3.131185 3.208122 3.222308 3.273654 3.483277   100
```

`system.time()` isn't precise enough to measure a 20% difference on such a short calculation.

Comment: Thanks. I will use microbenchmark from next time.